# How to configure settings.gradle for multiproject?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How should I structure my build.gradle and settings.gradle to include another project with own build and settings gradle files? Currently I get:

**Configuration with name 'default' not found.**

My settings.gradle:

```
include :sliding-layer'
project(':sliding-layer').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'modules/sliding-layer:Library')
```

and build.gradle:

```
compile project(':modules:sliding-layer')
```

Second project settings.gradle:

```
include ':Library'
include ':SlidingLayerSample'
```

and build.gradle (in root dir):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
  }
}

allprojects {
  group = 'com.6wunderkinder.slidinglayerlibrary'
  version = '1.1-SNAPSHOT'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-reporting'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one settings.gradle per build, but you can refer to nested projects in the top-level settings.gradle:

```
include ':sliding-layer:Library'
include ':sliding-layer:SlidingLayerSample'
```

Comment: I refer to them using syntax like that but the same error appears. I even tried using full path: "include ':modules/sliding-layer:Library'" and result is the same.
Of course Library can be build successfully as an independent project.